# Python: ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.foursquare-com', port=443)

Tags: python, foursquare

I'm having this issue while running the script:

(I'm using Spyder to build my script, but I'm trying at Jupyter Notebook and I'm getting the same error)

```
#STEP 3.8 - Get the URL request

LIMIT = 100

radius = 50

url = 'https://api.foursquare-com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(

CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION, neighbor_lat, neighbor_long, radius, LIMIT)

#STEP 3.9 - Get request and examinate the result

results = requests.get(url).json()

print(results)
```

**ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.foursquare-com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/venues/explore?&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&v=20180605&ll=43.806686299999996,-79.19435340000001&radius=500&limit=100 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))**

Comment: I think you made a typo with the url. Isn't it supposed to be `https://api.foursquare.com` instead of `https://api.foursquare-com`?

Comment: Yes Prateek!!! Thank you so much, it was my mistake, I couldn't recognize this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `headers` parameters in your `request.get`.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks Henrique, but I got my mistake from the previous comment as I use "-" instead of "."

Answer (score 0):

Try using the exceptions

```
results=" "
while results==" ":
    try:
        results = requests.get(url).json()
                 
    except:
        time.sleep(50)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

This is common error, after doing SSL to your VPS server, it only finds the url with **https://domanName.com**
in this case check you connection in you code File or .env file and
change connections from
**http://domainName.com** -- to -- **https://domainName.com**
I hope this will solve your problem
Thanks.